# How to make a function accessible in both window.load and document.ready?

Tags: jquery, function, methods

I have created a function that has the capability to copy the specific data in each table cells but my problem is that it cannot be accessed after the page is loaded when I put it in `$(window).load(function() {});` and if I also put it in `$(document).ready(function () {});`, some of the table cells is not having the result I want. I'm able to solve my problem by creating the function in both window.load and document.ready but it's not what I want since it's a bit space consuming and not a good coding practice. How can I achieve a result somewhat like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   myCreatedFunction();
});
$(window).load(function() {
   myCreatedFunction();
});
//and somewhere in the page in which can be accessed by both methods

var myCreatedFunction = function(){
    //some other actions
}
```

Comment: Your code should work, unless the page has already loaded, in which case the function isn't hoisted, so it won't be declared by the time you try to call it - either declare it up above, or use a function declaration instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for that one. It solved my problem. But it's not similar to your tagged duplicate question. Thanks.